# How do I show product details on product page (with modern template/skin)

Tags: product, magento-1.8, template

When I set the template/skin to modern, the product details disappear.

With default template, I can see the product details. Screen shot below
[image: With default template]
With Modern template, the product details disappear (Screen shot below)
[image: With Modern template]

Comment: copy description.phtml from app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/ and move it to app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that two things

1) the package name must be **default** if you set magento **modern** theme.

2) set the **modern** as per below snap shot.

[image]

you don't need to set Templates, Skin (Images / CSS) and Layout because Magento follow the fallback structure.

Comment: then mark ans is correct Buddy